# Click map close keyboard in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic3

In MapPage.xml I have ion-searchbar and map.
When click input in searchbar keyboard open.
Now I want when click over keyboard or click to map keyboard will close.
I'm try add event click in map or event click to ion-content and call Keyboard.close() but it not working
Here is my MapPage.xml

```
<ion-content (click)="clickContent()"> 
 <div class="map">
    <form action=".">
      <ion-searchbar #searchbar placeholder="{{'AreaSearch'|translate}}" [(ngModel)]="searchKey" (search)="searchKeyboard(searchKey)"
                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      </ion-searchbar>
    </form>
    <div id="map" #map></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I try with cases:

1:

```js
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
export class MapPage {
 constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard){}
}
```

and call

```js
this.keyboard.close()
```

2:

```js
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
```

and call

```js
Keyboard.close()
```

3:
add

```js
declare var google: any;
```

above @Component and call

```js
cordova.plugins.keyboard.close()
```

To call click ion-content I add

```js
clickContent(){
  console.log("click content")
  // call 1/3 event close keyboard for one case: 
  // this.keyboard.close()
  // Keyboard.close()
  // cordovar.plugin.keyboard.close()
}
```

Click map I add event:

```js
map.addListener('click', function() {
  console.log("click map")
  // call 1/3 event close keyboard for one case: 
  // Keyboard.close()
  // this.keyboard.close()
  // cordova.plugin.keyboard.close()
  });
```

```js
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

But all case not working. Some time keyboard close but after that it show.
How I can do it? Pleasse help me! Tkank every one.

I did it with js

```js
 $("#searchbar-input").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

$(".map").click(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        Keyboard.close();
      }, 400);

    });
```

Comment: Try putting the close in a setTimeout to see what happens

Comment: I did it with stop event. thank for your question

Comment: Can you post the answer

Comment: @PhilipBrack I added my js